# gmote-server on the device

Tags: raspbian, keyboard, mouse

is possible to running gmote server (android HID - mouse keyboard controller) on the device?
I've tried to run it but it says me:

..  "./GmoteServer.sh: line 2: java: command not found"

Here you can get the file http://www.gmote.org/server

Ideas? Thanks

Comment: Have you installed Java?

Comment: Yes Alex, trough.. sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre
and now when i start gmote server, it give me this error..

28-Oct-2012 10:59:56 org.gmote.server.GmoteServerUi sharedMain
WARNING: Gmote Version: 2.0.0
28-Oct-2012 10:59:56 org.gmote.server.GmoteServerUi sharedMain
WARNING: OperatingSystem: Linux
28-Oct-2012 11:00:57 org.gmote.server.GmoteServerUi sharedMain
SEVERE: jnidispatch (/com/sun/jna/linux-arm/libjnidispatch.so) not found in resource path
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: jnidispatch (/com/sun/jna/linux-arm/libjnidispatch.so) not found in resource path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you came across the same issue as in [this forum discussion](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=7820). Give it a try and specify the path to the JNA lib by the system parameter `jna.boot.library.path`. Add the option `-Djna.boot.library.path=/usr/lib/jni` to the `java` call in your `GmoteServer.sh` and see whether it works.